# DataTemplate и ItemsSource, как правильно задавать ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я создал шаблон DataGrid и поместил его в DataTemplate. Так же создал контейнер `ContentPresenter` куда буду выгружать шаблон!

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:TemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Models">
            <DataGrid Name="DataView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="True" HeadersVisibility="All" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ModelID"  Binding="{Binding ModelID}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name Model" Binding="{Binding NameFurniture}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding Cost}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SaleID" Binding="{Binding SaleID}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Height="30" Header="Model" Click="Model_Click"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="presenter"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Создал класс для переключения на этот шаблон:

```
  public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null && item != null)
        {
             if (item is ObservableCollection<Custsources>)
            { 

                return element.FindResource("Models") as DataTemplate;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Изменяю свойство Content `ContentPresenter`через кнопку, с кодом:

```
private void Model_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    presenter.Content = cust;
}

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        cust = new ObservableCollection<Custsources>();
        cust.Add(new Custsources() { ModelID = 1, NameFurniture = "Table", Description = "Size of the table 2x2", Cost = 30, SaleID = 1 });
    }
public ObservableCollection<Custsources> cust { get; set; }
```

И это прекрасно работает(возможно не идеально). Спасибо за помощь @Андрей NOP!!! Осталось разобраться как работает DataType)

Comment: Установите Content у ContentPresenter

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это не срабатывает. Я задал в методе `Model_Click` `presenter.Content = cust;`, где `cust` это коллекция элементов вида `cust = new ObservableCollection<Custsources>();` и получил на экране просто (Коллекция)

Comment: Логично, вы же в своем DataTemplateSelector не проверяете этот тип, возвращаете для него null, что есть пустой шаблон, а пустой шаблон только и умеет что отображать ToString значения

Comment: Вы же умеете отладчиком пользоваться? Ну поставьте брейкпоинт в свой DataTemplateSelector и посмотрите как он работает

Comment: @Андрей NOP, я понимаю, как работает мой DataTemplateSelector, он же ищет DataTemplate по имени. Так вопрос в том, почему не тянет ресурс. Я не понимаю что вы мне хотите сказать. Я уже больше недели ищу ответ и не как не пойму что не так я сделал.

Comment: Ну ок, смотрите вы написали условие: `element != null && item != null && item is string` когда оно истинно? Подходит ли это вам? Поставьте брейкпоинт и посмотрите какого типа элемент приходит в `item`

Comment: Убедитесь для начала что у вас именно эта строчка срабатывает `return element.FindResource("Models") as DataTemplate;`, а не эта `return null;` и тогда будем думать дальше

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да я изменил метод, теперь заходит, но всё равно не подгружает данные(( я отредактировал метод `SelectTemplate`

Comment: Ресурс находится?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет, выводит только шаблон, который выбран.

Comment: Я спрашиваю, шаблон правильный устанавливается теперь?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, теперь да, шаблон устанавливается правильно. Но данные не выводит

Comment: @АндрейNOP, добавил изображение.

Comment: Видимо DataContext не подхватывается. Пробуйте в DataGrid использовать не Binding, а Template finding Content. Ну или скиньте проект, я сам посмотрю, а то мы будем вечно переписываться

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо, что помогаете [проект](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13HW9WSzLC_GD5hqAmVIwBVMR6vW_2CKh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Вы в тексте вопроса обманули, у вас написано `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`, а в проекте на самом деле не так, я поправил — строчки появились: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpmUo.png

Comment: @АндрейNOP , ужас  это были последние мои попытки.... простите пожалуйста

Comment: @АндрейNOP те нужно было просто в ‘ItemsSource={Binding}’ и в этом была моя ошибка?(

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вопрос, почему не заполняет созданные колонки в шаблоне?

Comment: Что-то не так с биндингами, надо смотреть

Comment: Видимо, потому что вы и здесь обманули с биндингами, у вас в теле вопроса написано правильно (`{Binding ModelID}`), а в проекте — не так

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Спасибо большое.. без вас, я бы не разобрался!!!!

Comment: Отлично, запостите рабочий пример ответом, кому-нибудь еще пригодится. У меня, к сожалению, нет времени писать развернутый ответ.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был получен огромной помощью @Андрей NOP. Спасибо ему за это! Вопрос отредактирован всё работает)!!

Comment: Только в ответе надо размещать ответ